# Add a folder to the final vite output

Tags: javascript, build, vite, solid-js

Does *Vite* support adding a folder and its content into the final product? (Adding a folder in the `dist` directory)
If so, then how can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Vite's documentation on assets](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory):

> ### The `public` Directory
>
> If you have assets that are:
>
> - Never referenced in source code (e.g. `robots.txt`)
> - Must retain the exact same file name (without hashing)
> - ...or you simply don't want to have to import an asset first just to get its URL
>
> Then you can place the asset in a special `public` directory under
> your project root. Assets in this directory will be served at root
> path `/` during dev, and copied to the root of the dist directory
> as-is.
>
> The directory defaults to `<root>/public`, but can be configured via
> the [`publicDir` option](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#publicdir).
>
> Note that:
>
> - You should always reference `public` assets using root absolute path - for example, `public/icon.png` should be referenced in source code as `/icon.png`.
> - Assets in `public` cannot be imported from JavaScript.

If you move your files to the `public` directory, they will be included in the build. You can also [configure the `publicDir`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#publicdir) option to include a different folder, if you can't use the public folder.